# Android share only the socket variable between two activites (Will 'service' help)

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity, android-service

I guess this is too basic and as far as i searched i could not find any related questions.

I have an activity where i create a socket is created. I have three more activities that will read/write to the same socket. But I have to get the socket inside each activity. As far as i searched, the 'service' were to be the best option, but when i read through it, I think it is more of a background processing of data rather than storing just the variable for later use. Can you please let me know how to go forward?

I have 
classA : Socket creation.
classB : Write to the socket.
calssC : Read from the socket.

My initial idea was to create an obj of classA inside B and C but i think it will not work. Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use [Application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) instead of creating instance of Activity class for sharing fields or behavior between different components or Activities,services of your own Application

See following tutorials for sharing data between different components using Application class:

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state

http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-application-class.html

http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android#

Comment: @Prosper Hi, sorry for the late reply.
But, when i create a separate application class, SocketAppln and try to do the way as it is done in 1st link, it is not working.

For eg, the way to get the function call,
((HelloApplication)getApplication()).setGlobalVariable(10); 

does not work. It gives me a Left hand side must be a variable error.

Comment: @ManikandanKandasamy : plz post relevant code and application class code then i will try to help u more

Comment: Hi,
I set the socket to be static since i wont be making any changes to it once i connect. And, using ActivityA.socket i am accessing it. I know it is not the correct way to do it, but do you think if this will work?